# Xamarin c# Intent error with typeof(broadcasterclass)

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I try to build an alarm clock in Xamarin Forms. When I try to make an Intent(in Android) then some errors come during the runtime.

My ClockAndroid class where i call the Intent:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ClockAndroid))]
namespace AlarmClock.Droid
{
    class ClockAndroid : IClock
    {
        public void SetAlarm()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmBroadcast));
            var source = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Schedule the alarm for 30 se+conds from now!
            var am = (AlarmManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            am.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 5 * 1000, source);
        }

    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver (AlarmBroadcast):

```
namespace Wecker.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class AlarmBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

The Error is here:

```
var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AlarmBroadcast));
```

ErrorMessage:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

Comment: Hi, the code you provided works well for me, please post the code which can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the code...

I have debuged with xamarin live player and an android simulator.

The solution is to put it on a real device.